# How can states sue someone in a lower court?

Tags: united-states, constitution, supreme-court

Article III, section 2, clause 2 of the Constitution says

> In all Cases...in which a State shall be Party, the supreme Court shall have original Jurisdiction.

I would interpret this as meaning that when a state is the plaintiff, the Supreme Court should have original jurisdiction regardless of who the defendant is. But this is not the case — to give a recent example, in *[Trump v. Hawaii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trump_v._Hawaii)*, Hawaii filed suit in a district court. Why do lawsuits by states not invoke original jurisdiction of the Supreme Court?

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/41414/why-are-lawsuits-between-the-president-and-congress-not-automatically-sent-to-th), which concerns lawsuits between parties that are explicitly stated as *not* having original jurisdiction. It does not address the question of a state as a plaintiff.

Comment: The Supreme Court recently declined to take an original-jurisdiction lawsuit by a state against non-state parties: [Arizona v. Sackler, 151-Orig](https://www.supremecourt.gov/search.aspx?filename=/docket/docketfiles/html/public/22o151.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That section of the Constitution says that the Supreme Court has original jurisdiction when a state is a party to a case. It does not say that the Supreme Court has *exclusive* original jurisdiction, and Congress has given lower courts jurisdiction over some of those cases since the Judiciary Act of 1789. The courts have upheld this concurrent jurisdiction. The only situation where Congress has given *exclusive* jurisdiction to the Supreme Court is lawsuits between two states.

Comment: [Also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judiciary_Act_of_1789) exclusive jurisdiction "between a state and the United States". The fact that Hawaii sued Trump and not the US made a difference.

Comment: @Fizz That was true in 1789; it is no longer true.

Comment: What law changed that?

Comment: Exactly right +1

Comment: @Fizz - Not so much a change in law, though there were changes; but, rather, a change in interpretation. "Although Chief Justice Marshall apparently assumed the Court had exclusive jurisdiction of cases within its original jurisdiction, Congress from 1789 on gave the inferior federal courts concurrent jurisdiction in some classes of such cases. Sustained in the early years on circuit, this concurrent jurisdiction was finally approved by the Court itself." [Big download - 18.9MB.](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-CONAN-2017/pdf/GPO-CONAN-2017.pdf), p 871.

Comment: @Fizz - This seems to apply, generally. [U.S. Code § 1331.Federal question](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/28/1331) "The district courts shall have original jurisdiction of all civil actions arising under the Constitution, laws, or treaties of the United States." The earliest reference is June 25, 1948.

Comment: @Fizz I don’t know when it changed, [but it changed at some point.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/28/1251)

Comment: SCOTUS doesn't even necessarily accept original jurisdiction on cases simply because they involve two states.  They only accept them "as strictly necessary", and have turned away cases between states that tried to start at SCOTUS because it was deemed unnecessary, and that lower courts should settle more mundane disputes before SCOTUS needs to get involved.